# Php dropdown menu from another file

Tags: php, arrays, dropdown

I'm trying to create a state capital guessing game where a state will randomly generate and then from the dropdown list which contains all the capitals the user will have to guess the capital.  Anyway, he wants us to have a separate file with an array. The file is called city_info.php and the arrays look like this

```
$state_capitals = array(
    'Alabama' => 'Montgomery',
```

I'm having trouble getting the drop down list populate with all the capitals.

```
<?php
require_once "include/session.php";

if (!isset($session->valid)) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}

require_once "include/city_info.php";
/* DO NOT MODIFY THE ABOVE LINES !!!!! */

$states   = array_keys($state_capitals);
$capitals = array_values($state_capitals);
$cities   = array_merge($capitals, $other_cities);
sort($cities);

$params = (object) $_REQUEST;
print_r($params);

if (isset($params->guess)) {
    $state_capitals = $params->capitals;
    $answer         = $params->answer;
    $cities         = $params->city;

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" 
  content="no-cache, max-age=0, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<title>State Capital Guess Game</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#logout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
}

div {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#3399ff;
    display:inline-block
}

/* 
More style rules
*/
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onunload = function(){}</script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="logout" href="logout.php">Log out</a>

<h2>State Capital Guess Game</h2>

<form action="program.php" method="get">
<button type="submit">Start Over</button>
</form>

<!--- computational form -->

<div>
<p>What is the Capital of PA</p>


<select name="cities">
<?php
foreach ($city as $value):
?>
<option <?php
    if ($value == $params->city)
        echo "selected";
?>
><?php
    echo $value;
?></option>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="choose" value="Choose" />
</form>
</div>

<?php
echo $state_capitals;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one problem `<option value=`

Comment: another: you create `$cities` but loop `$city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you phrase your question, this sounds like it could be homework. Many people on SO are glad to help with homework, however, some are not; so as a courtesy when asking a question about homework follow these guidelines: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. You may already know this, but wanted to cover the basics just in case.

On to your question. I'll clean things up a bit so it's not so hard to follow the HTML/PHP. This should work if you substitute your current code:

```
<select name="cities">
<?php
    $options = "";
    foreach ($cities as $value){
        $options .= '<option value="' . $value . '"';
        if ($value == $params->city)
            $options .= ' selected';
        $options .= '>' . $value . '</option>';
    }
    echo $options;
?>
</select>
```

This way you're only switching between HTML/PHP once. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Michael! I did not know about the homework guidelines so thank you very much... I will follow them to a tee. Thank you that code worked for me:)

Comment: @PatrickJudePike Glad to hear it worked out. Feel free to check this as the answer if you like. Thanks!

Comment: At further glance Michael with the code changes the only thing that shows up in the drop down menu is just "$value" instead of all the capitals names.

Comment: @PatrickJudePike Sorry! Forgot the additional single quotes around that last `$options` line. I've corrected it now. Now it should show the capitals' names. Here's the edited line: `$options .= '>' . $value . '</option>';`

Comment: Thank you that works now:) I really appreciate it! If I have any questions in the future would you be open to helping? I've been trying to teach myself more php to complete this program but I'm sure I'll run into problems. Thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickJudePike I'd be happy to help. If you wouldn't mind checking this as the answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I selected your answer as the best answer! After struggling to fix another problem I have posted another question if you would like to check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683587/php-game-coding-a-prompt-when-answer-is-correct